# Android or iOS navigation app that gives an alert when close to a speed camera in France

Tags: android, ios, maps, car

I am looking for Android or iOS application that can give me an alert whenever I am close to a speed camera in France when driving. My only requirement is that the application misses as few speed cameras as possible. It's OK if the application focuses on static speed cameras only or mobile speed cameras only: I am fine using multiple applications concurrently.

Comment: I am using http://navmii.com/ and am very pleased with it (seems the most fully featured while also having offline maps, so that I don't need to use data connection).  It has both speed camera & excess speed alerts, but I won't post this as an answer as I don’t know about its coverage in France.

Comment: Incidentally, there is (almost?) always a sign on the road before static speed cameras and mobile speed cameras are rare.

Comment: I have no car, so I cannot recommend anything from my own experience – but for Android, you might wish to take a look at my [Traffic Info, Jam, & Speed Cams](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_trafficinfo) collection :)

Comment: @Izzy Great list! Waze + Radardroid Pro saved my bank account in the US (police cars) and Brazil (fixed radars), going to try next week in France :-)

Comment: @Relaxed Cool! A few years ago I heard the French government was thinking of removing speed radar signs, unsure what they eventually decided.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, can we run Navmii in the bakground just to get the radar alerts?

Comment: Sorry, Frank, I haven't tried that (and am currently without a 'phone). It's free, so why not download it, try it out & post back here to help others?

Comment: It is forbidden in France to specify exact locations of fixed and mobile speedcameras. That's why they use "security zones". If they catch you with your TomTom, Coyote or so not set to "use security zones", you get a quite heavy fine. You could also try to stick to the max speed...

Comment: @pivertigo police enforcement should not be used as a tax collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can use [iCoyote Avertisseur de dangers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coyotesystems.android&hl=en) (50 EUR/year, Android/iOS) in the background +  [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze&hl=en) (free, Android/iOS) in the foreground.

---

The official version of iCoyote doesn't specify the precise location of speed cameras: it only shows 4-km long enforcement zones, where speed cameras are located. However, from what I have been told, the radar is conveniently always at 2/3 of the zone (with a discrete but noticeable signal). The version I had was displaying the exact locations of speed radars so I can't confirm regarding the 2/3 rule. iCoyote can be configured to run in the background and only show up whenever there is a speed radar ahead.

As Relaxed indicated, Waze also doesn't specify the precise location of speed cameras: it only shows enforcement zones, where speed cameras are located. Also, while iCoyote didn't miss any speed radars when I was in France, I believe Waze missed a few ones. However, Waze is a good complement to iCoyote to receive warnings about the presence of police cars, so in the end I chose to have Waze in the foreground and iCoyote in the background.

---

Even though iCoyote didn't miss any speed radars, I like to keep an eye open, so I made a list of speed camera type that are present in France:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

(Some of these photos are protected by the GFDL licence and the CC-BY-SA licence. [Céréales killer](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilisateur:C%C3%A9r%C3%A9ales_Killer) is one of the photographer.)

Lastly, some [autonomous radars](http://lci.tf1.fr/france/societe/inauguration-d-un-radar-autonome-c-est-quoi-ce-nouveau-radar-8629690.html) are now being deployed. Unsure yet how accurate iCoyote or Waze will be for these ones, and how often they'll be moved around.

---

[image] [image]

Waze in France only indicates enforcement zone (left screenshot). In more developed countries where information can legally be shared, Waze indicates the exact location of speed radars (right screenshot).

---

[image] [image]
<sup>iCoyote showing: the exact location of speed radars / *zone de dangers* (enforcement zone) only</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Waze is a crowd sourced GPS application for Android. Users provide info on traffic, construction, speed traps, cameras and objects on the road. When you are nearing an item Waze informs you and you can confirm its existence or enter new warnings for others.

https://www.waze.com/

Comment: Thanks, are there enough users in France to make it decently reliable? Also, does it warn about static speed cameras?

Comment: Not sure about France. All the info is crowd driven so its up to users to enter when they see speed cameras or signs stating cameras exist.

Comment: AFAIK, Waze deactivated this functionality in France in 2011 after the government announced new rules designed to fight such apps. It might still be possible to reactivate it by manually editing some config file or to get approximate locations (e.g. info about “dangerous zones” rather than “here is a speed camera” signal).