# Android or iOS navigation app that gives an alert when close to a speed camera in Spain

Tags: android, ios, maps, finance, car

I am looking for Android or iOS application that can give me an alert whenever I am close to a speed camera in Spain when driving. My only requirement is that the application misses as few speed cameras as possible. It's OK if the application focuses on static speed cameras only or mobile speed cameras only: I am fine using multiple applications concurrently.

Related: [Getting a "Número de Identidad de Extranjero" (NIE number) for a 10-day trip in Spain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89978/1810)

Comment: I take it your [candidates from France](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19037/185) don't fit? I'd expected some to do, according to the description in your answer there.

Comment: @Izzy I'm not sure how good Waze and iCoyote work in Spain: there might be different laws pertaining to programs warning drivers for speed cameras, perhaps Spanish prefer to use some other the programs (iCoyote is originally French, Waze is from LA), etc. For example, when I was in south Korea, they had their own local speed radar program that worked very well: [Kakao Navi (카카오내비)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/32415/903). I cannot try Waze/iCoyote/etc. in Spain at the moment since I am not currently in Spain: I just plan to spend 10 days there in early April.

Comment: And you're driving fast #D OK, fair enough. I just wanted to make sure you didn't forget having asked a few speed-cam recommendations already (more of them in the "related" section :) Good luck then!